# how to decode this Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how to decode this Javascript

the code is here.. [encoded js](http://pastebin.com/4Epdq2ei)

I have tried online tools but no success

I will be really happy if any one decode this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

http://matthewfl.com/unPacker.html

---

It looks like the unpacked source also contains some packed sections (i.e. some code was packed twice), so you'll need to find those sections and unpack them as well.

It also has lots of base64 strings in it, which are apparently useless, because they appear like this:

```
document.big_pipe1321735186 = function () {
    ('...long base64 string here...')
};
delete document.big_pipe1321735186;
```

So you can ignore those sections.

Comment: It decoded it just fine. The original source had a lot of base64 strings in it, but it's decoded to the original source. Note the presence of functions like `attscr` and `document.big_pipe1321735186`.

Comment: Sure it can... https://gist.github.com/555cafab773b8941679f Just because you dont like the result doesn't mean it didn't work.  But you need to realize you are never getting back the original source here, you are simply making the obfuscated version a bit more readable.

Comment: yea still it has some eval(p,a,c,k,e,d) functions..can i get clear deocoder please.i will be really thank full

Comment: @JustinBiaber no, do the work yourself; find those sections and paste them into the decoder. Then substitute them in. This isn't rocket science.

Comment: oh ok..but i tried to paste only that part..but its not decoding

Comment: i tried to decode this seperate part it did not work http://pastebin.com/LTMYyeGF

Comment: You can decode the base64 parts using an online decoder
http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

http://base64-decoder.com

http://ostermiller.org/calc/encode.html

are a few you can use